# Rearrange arrays in this order

Tags: c#

Given array `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`

write it as one digit from the front and the second from the back and so on

> ex: 123456 will return 162534
>
> 130 will return 103

I did this but I am having difficulty on the logic to achieve this.
Please help:

```
public int solution(int A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)

    string S = A.ToString();
    int [] intArray = new int[S.Length];

    for(int i=0; i < S.Length; i++)
        intArray[i] = int.Parse(S[i]);

    List<string> newCol = new List<string>();
        newCol.Add(intArray[0]);

    for(int i=1; i < intArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if ()
           newCol.Add(intArray[i])

    }
```

Comment: One way to achieve this is: iterate on half the array (`intArray.Length / 2`), and at first iteration take the first and last digit, then at second iteration take the second first and second last, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the number of elements in the array is even or odd, in order to know when to finish the loop (so 1234567x doesn't have a problem with the blank number which would normally be checked - I'm saying about x-th position). Declare now a temporary array `temp` with a size of the initial one, so you will be able to save your new data there. Then, your loop would start from `i=0` (not `i=1`, as array indexing for `n` elements is `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1`) and will finish on the half of the input array length. Inside the loop, take `i`-th element and save it in `2*i`-th place in `temp`, take `n-1-i`-th element and save it in `2*i-1`-th element, then iterate `i`. After the loop is done, your sequence will be finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedo code, it gets two elements at a time and I use the counter K & J to get elements from the start & end.

```
string S = A.ToString(); 
char[] res = new char[S.Length];
int j = 1;
int k = 0;
 for(int i=0; i < S.Length; i++)
 { 
   res[i] = S[k];
   if (i + 1 > S.Length) break;
   res[i + 1] = S[S.Length - j,1];
   i+=1;
   j++;
   k++;
 }
 return res.ToString()
```

Written on my phone, there maybe bugs but should give you the idea.

Get these fundamentals downpat & use a debugger to make sure you understand how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A simple approach with for loop

```
public  int solution(int A) {
        var charArray=A.ToString().ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0,j=charArray.Length-1; i<=j; i++,j--)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(" ("+i+","+j+")");
            sb.Append(charArray[i]);
            if(i!=j)
                sb.Append(charArray[j]);
            //Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

    return (Int32.Parse(sb.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
var sourceArray = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };    

var targetArray = Enumerable.Range(0, sourceArray.Length)
    .Select(sourceIndex => sourceArray[sourceIndex % 2 == 0 ? 
            sourceIndex / 2 : // even case, take from start
            sourceArray.Length - (sourceIndex + 1) / 2] // odd case, take from end
            );
// 1,6,2,5,3,4
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', targetArray));
```

So here we have a transformation of the source index to the required target index.

`Enumerable.Range` is just used to get the sequence of source indices, so in this example 0 to 5. Then we transform each number to the target index with the following ternary expression:

Condition: `sourceIndex % 2 == 0` is the number even?

If so, `sourceIndex / 2` our target index is half that number. So, 0 becomes zero, 2 becomes 1, 4 becomes 2, etc. So we're taking every other number from the start of the array.

If not, then the target is the length of the array minus half the current index + 1. So given a source index of 1 and array length of 6, (6 - 1 + 1 / 2) = 5, the last position in the array.